# Como fazer uma atraso ou ocasionar uma espera no Android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho um `for` onde ele varre um vetor `String`, enviando comando acada incremento .

```
for(int i=0; i < msg.size(); i++)
{
     enviarComando(msg.get(i));
}
```

Quando ele enviar quero que ele aguarde 1 segundo a cada envio.

Tentei usar e esse código dentro `for`, mas não obtive sucesso, ele não aguarda 1 segundos esperado.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {


   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Aqui acho que tem o exemplo do que você procura.
[Future e Futures Task](https://www.devmedia.com.br/processamento-assincrono-em-java-com-future-e-futuretask/33851)

Answer (score 3):

O problema, aparentemente, é que você está tentando fazer esse delay dentro da UIThread (ou Main Thread se preferir). Por definição a UIThread não pode conter qualquer elemento que seja blocante ao usuário(o que também incluem métodos de delay como Thread.sleep()) logo para resolver seu problema basta lançar uma nova thread e executar seu processamento nesta nova thread:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    for(int i=0; i < msg.size(); i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }

         enviarComando(msg.get(i));
    }
}).start();
```